# Does AJAX callback functions work differently for BEF views?

Tags: 7, ajax, forms, views

I am breaking my head since last two days to implement dependent drop down list. I have followed so many examples in the internet, SE and examples project but for some reason the simple thing isn't working. So I got doubt that the different could be because I am trying to alter an BEF Form.

What I am trying to do is to alter the better exposed form element to populate with locations (second dropdown)of selected city (first dropdown). It looks like there is some ajax call being made because I get the "Please wait..." with spinning icon is displayed but in the end second drop down remains unchanged.

After so much tries I at last decided to test the code with drupal examples project. I have simply put the code into my hook_form_alter (with small tweeks like changing function,elements names etc)  to see if it works. But unfortunately it isn't working so that put me in doubt whether the callback function is called or not so I just added a die statement in the callback function and I got no php error meaning that call back never called.

Is there any different implementation for ajax for BEF views? also my form is themed does it also has any impact?

This is how my form looks like after adding the hook_form_alter. You can see the two new form elements are added in the bottom.

[image]

> **Update:**
>
> I can see ajax errors in the recent logs which doesnt give much useful information
>
> ```
> Location  http://localhost/system/ajax
> Referrer  http://localhost/
> Message   Invalid form POST data.
> Severity  warning
> ```

Below is the complete code

```
function tdyards_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-apartments-page-6' /*|| $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-apartments-city-search-results-page'*/) {

        $firstoptions = first_dropdown_options();

        $selected = isset($form_state['values']['first']) ? $form_state['values']['first'] : key($firstoptions);

        $form['first'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'Instrument Type',
            '#options' => $firstoptions,
            '#default_value' => $selected,
            '#ajax' => array(
              'callback' => 'first_call_back',
              'wrapper' => 'second-replace',
            ),
          );

        $form['second'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $firstoptions[$selected] . ' ' . t('Instruments'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="second-replace">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#options' => second_dropdown_options($selected),
            '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['second']) ? $form_state['values']['second'] : '',
          );

    }
}
//
function first_dropdown_options(){
    return drupal_map_assoc(
            array(
              t('String'),
              t('Woodwind'),
              t('Brass'),
              t('Percussion'),
            )
          );
}
//
function second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    t('String') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Violin'),
        t('Viola'),
        t('Cello'),
        t('Double Bass'),
      )
    ),
    t('Woodwind') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Flute'),
        t('Clarinet'),
        t('Oboe'),
        t('Bassoon'),
      )
    ),
    t('Brass') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Trumpet'),
        t('Trombone'),
        t('French Horn'),
        t('Euphonium'),
      )
    ),
    t('Percussion') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Bass Drum'),
        t('Timpani'),
        t('Snare Drum'),
        t('Tambourine'),
      )
    ),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
}
//
function first_call_back($form, $form_state) {
  die("call back function"); //added for testing
  return $form['second'];
}
```